# How to resize current browser window in Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, responsive-design, selenium-webdriver, window-resize

I need to resize the browser as 300x400 during executing the Selenium automated tests. How can I resize the browser window in Selenium WebDriver (aka, Selenium 2) with Java?

[Note: It needs to resize the browser window for testing Responsive Web Design (RWD)]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get a reference to the current window with `driver.manage().window()`. And the `window` has a [`setSize()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#setSize(org.openqa.selenium.Dimension)) method, so you could try

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(800, 600);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Responsive Design it's better if you don't use fixed data, in this case screen resolution - users need most often (cause it's much less prone to errors) :

```
_driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

or

```
_driver.manage().window().fullScreen();
```

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works (to make tab in full screen only) for you, go for it:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

where

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\softwares\chromedriver.exe")
```

or could be any other webdriver locations.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Chrome capability to resize the window.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=800,480");

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

After all comments above, I noticed that the suggestion below was not mentioned yet. It resolved the issue I had in my project. I hope it might solve your problem.

### Java

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```