# How to set the browser resolution to 2610*1610 using Selenium WebDriver in IE11

Tags: selenium, web

I want to set the IE11 browser resolution to 2610*1610 using Selenium IE driver automatically through scripts.

Comment: Which language binding are you using?

Answer (score 1):

He added JDBC as a tag so I guess Java.
However, it was answered in this thread:
[How to resize current browser window in Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664433/how-to-resize-current-browser-window-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

/*Try this*/

```
 WebDriver dr=new FirefoxDriver();
```

dr.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(2610,1610));